# Link error building libpng and zlib with CMAKE, FetchContent and Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10 x64

Tags: cmake, libpng

I'm trying to build libpng with CMAKE, but it requires zlib, so I'm trying to build them both but not having any luck. I like FetchContent so I can specify a GIT_TAG and easily update that in the future if needed. For now I have just a blank test.c file to illustrate the problem.

I get these link errors:

```
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals 
MinimalApp\out\build\x64-Debug\_deps\libpng-build\png-fix-itxt.exe

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol crc32 referenced in function main
```

When I build with this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)

include(FetchContent)

project(MinimalApp)

FetchContent_Declare(
    zlib
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
    GIT_TAG        v1.2.11
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(zlib)

set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${zlib_SOURCE_DIR} ${zlib_BINARY_DIR})
set(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB ON CACHE BOOL "Custom zlib Location, else find_package is used")

FetchContent_Declare(
    libpng
    GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glennrp/libpng.git
    GIT_TAG        v1.6.37
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libpng)

include_directories(
    ${libpng_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${libpng_BINARY_DIR}
)

add_library(MinimalApp SHARED 
    "test.c"
)

set_target_properties(MinimalApp PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/x64
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/x64
)
```

My test.c file is blank.

Comment: It seems you are still building them *separately*, so libpng will still have no knowledge of zlib. Building libpng like this would imply you already have zlib **installed** and accessible somewhere on your machine.

Comment: Well I'm trying to build zlib first and then tell libpng where zlib was built so I could build libpng second. From libpng's CMakeLists.txt, I thought that could be done like this:

`
# Allow users to specify location of Zlib.
# Useful if zlib is being built alongside this as a sub-project.
option(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB "Custom zlib Location, else find_package is used" OFF)

if(NOT PNG_BUILD_ZLIB)
  find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently and I believe you also need to set the `ZLIB_LIBRARY` cmake variable. libpng expects this variable to be set if you are using `PNG_BUILD_ZLIB`.

This can be as simple as:

```
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY zlib)
```